# Should I use "where" or "that" in this context?

Tags: where

Is it appropriate to use "where" in this sentence:

> "They made me testify. Sometimes they asked questions where you'd think: Are you crazy to ask this?"

Comment: I think it's a bit *casual/informal*, but it's a quick, easily understood "spatial metaphor", Most painstakingly, *...they asked questions **that would make you** think [blah blah]*.

Comment: If spoken, I think I would understand this perfectly.  In writing, it's a little [garden pathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence).

Comment: True. _That_ passes in speech, but only because it goes fast. In writing, @Nick's description is just about right on.

Comment: @Nick2253, thanks for the link to 'garden pathy', new to me, and fits in with what I've been trying to express, probably badly, about when phrases should be hyphenated.